# How to draw a rectangle with width programmatically determined in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying a draw a red rectangle covering 40% of the width of a white rectangle in android.

xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:height="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/level_to_next"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:height="10dp"
            android:width="0dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorRed_80" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

However, setting width to item with id level_to_next has no effect in xml file. Red rectangle covers the whole width of white rectangle.

How can I control the width of the red rectangle?

Comment: Nice question. My doubt too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height and width of both rectangles like the following. I changed the sizes to better see the rectangles on the screen, but you can change them to something else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="100dp"
                android:width="100dp"  />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/level_to_next"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="40dp"
                android:width="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorRed_80" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: how can I use code to change the width from 40dp to say 50 dp?

Comment: For API 23+ you can use `setLayerWidth()` and `setLayerHeight()`. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerWidth(int,%20int)). For APIs less than 23, you will have to search around for a possible solution and you may need to pursue a different approach.